# How to change the alpha of a UILabel by tapping?

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel, alpha

I have an iOS (4.0) app that I would like to change the alpha of a specific UILabel of just by taping anywhere on the screen.  I don't have my interface done programmatically, I just used the interface builder to place the labels for things on the screen.

How can I use a tap gesture to change the alpha of a specific UILabel in my program?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In viewDidLoad:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *oneTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapAction:)];
    [oneTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [oneTap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    [self.view oneTap];
```

Then define the method:

```
-(void)tapAction:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture 
    {
          [self.yourLabel setAlpha:0.5f]; // set the alpha to whatever you want, or animate the fade, whatever
    }
```

Comment: This worked great, except I added:

`[self.view addGestureRecognizer:oneTap];`

and removed: `[self.view oneTap];`

Comment: Make sure `userInteractionEnabled` is `YES` on the `UILabel` if you want the tap to be for just the label (though you say in your question you want to tap anywhere).

Answer (score -1):

```
-(IBAction)myPressedButton:(id)sender { 
    float x;
    x = theLabel.alpha;
    foat a=0.1;
    self.theLabel.alpha = x-a;
}
```

Comment: This is only valid for `UIControl`s.